# Signal handlers reset every time

Tags: signals

I'm writing a C program that does the following:

Monitors which signals are sent to it. Counts how many times SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 have been sent. Terminates when SIGTERM has been sent but first prints out how many times SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 have been sent.

Please note that this is a problem from class, so it's not supposed to really have any usage, just to test us. Also, no other signals except for the mentioned three will be sent.

This is what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int sigUsr1Count = 0;
int sigUsr2Count = 0;

static void sighandler(int signum){
    switch(signum){
        case SIGUSR1:
            sigUsr1Count++;
            break;
        case SIGUSR2:
            sigUsr2Count++;
            break;
        case SIGTERM:
            printf("%d %d\n", sigUsr1Count, sigUsr2Count);
            exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    pid_t mypid = getpid();
    fprintf(stderr, "My PID is %d\n", mypid);

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = 0; 
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = sighandler;
    iAssert(-1 != sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL), "sigaction1 failed");
    iAssert(-1 != sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL), "sigaction1 failed");
    iAssert(-1 != sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL), "sigaction1 failed");

    while(true){
        fprintf(stderr, "Waiting...\n");
        sleep(3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've read on a forum somewhere that, when using `sigaction`, signal handlers will NOT be reset to default unless the `sa_flags` field is set to `SA_RESETHAND`. However, that does not seem to be the case with me. (The man page describes the `SA_RESETHAND` flag but is not explicit about the action in the situation where it's omitted.)

When I run the program, it will only go to my handlers the first time SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 are sent, after that the program terminates with the message:

```
User defined signal 1 (or 2)
```

In that sense, the program only outputs the correct values if either: SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 haven't been sent at all, or each of them has been sent at most once.

The `iAssert` macro & function:

```
#define iAssert(cond, msg) crash(cond, msg, __LINE__)
void crash(bool cond, char * msg, int line){
    if(!cond){
        perror(msg);
        fprintf(stderr, "at line %d\n", line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Compilation methods that I've already tried (same with each of them):

```
gcc 1.c
gcc -std=c99 1.c
gcc -std=c11 1.c
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: "_I've read somewhere_" hopefully you mean the man page (`man sigaction`)?

Comment: Yes and no. In the man pages it says that adding that flag will cause the handlers to be reset but it doesn't say that not adding it won't do it. It was another Linux forum where I specifically read that not setting it will cause the handlers not to be reset.

Comment: Once I've added sufficient boilerplate to make this code compile as C++ it works for me. What OS and or Distribution/Version are you using?

Comment: It's elementaryOS Juno. But I'm not sure whether this is distro-related. I've also tried running this code on my university's server (an online grader app) and the program behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Debian Linux with `gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516`

Comment: I...don't quite understand, you want me to compile like that?

Comment: How did you compile it? (Please add that to your question, along with any code changes necessary to make it a complete example.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87872/discussion-between-koy-and-roaima).

Comment: You're not initializing `sa.sa_flags`, the `sa` variable is on the *stack*, so it may contain whatever garbage happens to be there (including `SA_RESETHAND`). Fix that bug (`sa.sa_flags = 0; sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask)`) and then edit the question. Also notice that you should not call `printf` from signal handlers.

Comment: @mosvy I've done what you said, still the same.

Comment: @Koy I don't see it.

Comment: You're probably still using the old binary; fwiw, the cc -std=99 should've died with an error. run your prog with strace to see the exact args passed to sigaction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I recompiled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87911/discussion-between-koy-and-mosvy).

Comment: @Koy I don't do chat, sorry. If you iron out all bugs (ie include `stdbool.h`), your program will still need to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to something >= 200112L in order to compile with `-std=c99`. FWIW, sigaction will **not** reset the handler unless given the ` SA_RESETHAND` flag is set -- that's standard mandated.

Answer (score 0):

Well since all the comments turned out to be equally useless (no offence), I've decided to take a different approach.

Instead of `sigaction` I've used the `signal` system call. I've also modified a few other things. Since `printf` is not a signal-safe function I've introduced a global variable named `shouldStop` which is by default set to `false` and then changed to `true` with `SIGTERM` handler. The printing is then done inside the `main` function.

Here's the code:

```
int sigUsr1Count = 0;
int sigUsr2Count = 0;

bool shouldStop = false;

static void sighandler(int signum){
    switch(signum){
        case SIGUSR1:
            sigUsr1Count++;
            break;
        case SIGUSR2:
            sigUsr2Count++;
            break;
    }
}

static void termhandler(int signum){
    shouldStop = true;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    pid_t mypid = getpid();
    fprintf(stderr, "My PID is %d\n", mypid);

    iAssert(SIG_ERR != signal(SIGUSR1, sighandler), "signal1 failed");
    iAssert(SIG_ERR != signal(SIGUSR2, sighandler), "signal2 failed");
    iAssert(SIG_ERR != signal(SIGTERM, termhandler), "signal3 failed");

    do{

    }while(!shouldStop);
    printf("%d %d\n", sigUsr1Count, sigUsr2Count);

    return 0;
}
```

And it works fine the way I wanted it.

Thanks anyway.